# How to use user inputed mathematical integer function?

Tags: python, function

I started working on my first Python code today and got the basis of my program working okay until I tried to take user input. A simple example:

```
import numpy
A = set()
max = 10**3;

def f(k):
    return 2*k+1

g = (f(k) for k in range(max));
A.update(g);
print("A = ", A)
```

It's just filling a set. It works fine (except for being extremely slow) until I try to let input data define the function:

```
func = input("Input a function: ")

def f(k):
    return func

g = (f(k) for k in range(max));
A.update(g);
print("A = ", A)
```

This returns `A = {'2*k+1'}`, if I give it 2*k+1 as input.

How do I get it to work like my original code with user input? I have found some examples here and elsewhere regarding similar problems, but in those cases there where trig functions involved and I must keep floats away from this code =)

I am using Python 3.9 in PyCharm 2021.2.2 (Community Edition), in case that that info is relevant.

Comment: Look at the built-in "eval" function. Be aware that it is very dangerous because it can execute arbitrary functions which may damage or steal data if you can't control the input given to the function. There are also external libraries which can safely parse and process an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` does always return a string. So, the `f(k)` function is always returning the string that was inputed, not the result of the code inside that string. You should use `eval(func)` in the defenition of `f(k)` instead.

**Note:** The use of `eval` can cause any malicious code in the input to be executed. So, *only use it when you can control the input completely* and there are no other ways of doing it.

I would also recommend to use `range(1,max+1)`, such that you get the answers for 1 to max instaed of 0 to max -1. (range never includes the ending value)
In the code that is given, the numpy module is not used. If nothing of your further code uses it, you can remove the import.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! Thanks for the heads up, but I had noticed that `range()` is using a half open interval when I started testing. Just removed most of the unnecessary code to make the example as small as possible. And in the original code `max` goes to infinity, so +1 doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

you could pass the definition of the function as an input using the python lambda function. Run below code, and pass `f = lambda x: 2*x+1` as input, you will see result 5 got printed.

```
func = input("Input a function: ")
exec(func)
print(f(2))
```

you could also get the function name by parsing from the input string, and running with it with the [globals](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/globals).

```
func = input("Input a function: ")
exec(func)
function_name = func.split('=')[0].strip()
func_to_run = globals()[function_name]
print(func_to_run(2))
```